# Power Query Operation to append 3 categorical columns and their respective measures

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to append 3 date columns from different months into single column (this stage has been reached post multiple operations) into a single one in Power Query editior. Not sure how to do this

From this :

[Actual Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDdS8.png)

To this :

[Desired State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcEFv.png)

I tried Unpivoting, Transpose etc but not getting the desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your column names are:

```
Date | Count | Date1 | Count1 | Date2 | Count2
```

Since you are not allowed to have duplicate column names.

You can achieve what you need, by appending columns...

```
...
...
  PreAppend = #"Your Previous Step",
  Appended = Table.FromColumns({
    PreAppend[Date] & PreAppend[Date1] & PreAppend[Date2],
    PreAppend[Count] & PreAppend[Count1] & PreAppend[Count2]
    }, { "Date", "Count" })
in
  Appended
```

This alternative will append the even and odd columns togther:

```
...
...
  tblColumns = Table.ToColumns(#"Your Previous Step"),
  Appended = Table.FromColumns({
    List.Combine(List.Alternate(tblColumns, 1, 1, 1)),
    List.Combine(List.Alternate(tblColumns, 1, 1))
    }, {"Date", "Count"})
in
  Appended
```

Comment: Worked as expected, Any idea how to modify basis addition of new date columns, as this is live data and monthly data will get added post LWD of the month

Comment: @VinitDawane Will your resultant table be in the same format (`Date|Count|Date|Count...`) with extra column pairs? Are there any other columns in this data set that need to be considered?

Comment: Added alternative answer above to append the even and odd columns. If you have other columns that shouldn't be included, then have these moved to the front, and then update `List.Alternate` to have an offset).